# How to trace Windows 7 Mobile broadband?

Tags: windows-7, mobile-broadband

I know that I can enable mobile broadband tracing with

```
netsh mbn set tracing mode=yes
```

**But where all the trace files will go to?**

Here is all information that I can find about this issue:

```
Usage: set tracing [mode=]yes|no

Parameters:

Tag           Value
mode        - One of the following values:
              yes: Enables tracing for Mobile Broadband.
              no:  Disables tracing for Mobile Broadband.

Remarks:

If enabled then the trace logs for Mobile Broadband will be collected
and saved to the trace files.

The parameter mode is required. If mode is set to disable, tracing will
be stopped.


Examples:

set tracing mode=yes
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be found here:

```
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI
```